# ReSharper XAML warning: Invalid resource type: expected type is 'Brush', actual type is 'SolidColorBrush'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resharper

ReSharper underlines with a red curvy line background bindings in my XAML with the following warning:

> Invalid resource type: expected type is 'Brush', actual type is
>   'SolidColorBrush'

For instance in the binding below the word 'StandardPanelBrush' is underlined with the red line:

```
Background="{StaticResource StandardPanelBrush}"
```

Surely SolidColorBrush is a Brush so it shouldn't show an error here. I expect my XAML to have no warnings at all. Why is this error shown?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and had a look on the Resharper YouTrack site, appears this has been reported previously.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-381060

Comment: Update: This seems to have been fixed in ReSharper 9.1.1